# How to loop over files in natural order in Bash?

Tags: bash, natural-sort

I am looping over all the files in a directory with the following command:

```
for i in *.fas; do some_code; done;
```

However, I get them in this order

```
vvchr1.fas  
vvchr10.fas  
vvchr11.fas
vvchr2.fas
...
```

instead of

```
vvchr1.fas
vvchr2.fas
vvchr3.fas
...
```

what is natural order.

I have tried sort command, but to no avail.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
readarray -d '' entries < <(printf '%s\0' *.fas | sort -zV)
for entry in "${entries[@]}"; do
  # do something with $entry
done
```

where `printf '%s\0' *.fas` yields a NUL separated list of directory entries with the extension `.fas`, and `sort -zV` sorts them in natural order.

Note that you need GNU sort installed in order for this to work.

Answer (score 12):

With option **sort -g** it compares according to general numerical value

```
 for FILE in `ls ./raw/ | sort -g`; do echo "$FILE"; done
```

0.log
1.log
2.log
...
10.log
11.log

This will only work if the name of the files are numerical. If they are string you will get them in alphabetical order. E.g.:

```
 for FILE in `ls ./raw/* | sort -g`; do echo "$FILE"; done
```

raw/0.log
raw/10.log
raw/11.log
...
raw/2.log

Answer (score 4):

You will get the files in ASCII order. This means that `vvchr10*` comes before `vvchr2*`. I realise that you can not rename your files (my bioinformatician brain tells me they contain chromosome data, and we simply don't call chromosome 1 "chr01"), so here's another solution (not using `sort -V` which I can't find on any operating system I'm using):

```
ls *.fas | sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\)/\1 \2/' | sort -k2,2n | tr -d ' ' |
while read filename; do
  # do work with $filename
done
```

This is a bit convoluted and will not work with filenames containing spaces.

Another solution: Suppose we'd like to iterate over the files in size-order instead, which might be more appropriate for some bioinformatics tasks:

```
du *.fas | sort -k2,2n |
while read filesize filename; do
  # do work with $filename
done
```

To reverse the sorting, just add `r` after `-k2,2n` (to get `-k2,2nr`).

Answer (score 2):

You mean that files with the number 10 comes before files with number 3 in your list? Thats because `ls` sorts its result very simple, so `something-10.whatever` is *smaller* than `something-3.whatever`.

One solution is to rename all files so they have the same number of digits (the files with single-digit in them start with `0` in the number).

Comment: Yes. I see, thanks. However I did not name files, just downloaded them:)

Comment: Try `sort -n`. That sorts contiguous blocks of numbers in numerical order. While "10a" still precedes "1a", at least "1-a" precedes "10-a".

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS= read -r file ; do
    ls -l "$file" # or whatever
done < <(find . -name '*.fas' 2>/dev/null | sed -r -e 's/([0-9]+)/ \1/' | sort -k 2 -n | sed -e 's/ //;')
```

Solves the problem, presuming the file naming stays consistent, doesn't rely on very-recent versions of GNU `sort`, does not rely on reading the output of `ls` and doesn't fall victim to the pipe-to-while problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You've forgotten a bracket in the end of <(find . -name '*.fas' 2>/dev/null | sed -r -e 's/([0-9]+)/ \1/' | sort -k 2 -n | sed -e 's/ //;')

Comment: @Andrew: in over a decade you are the first one to notice. This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kusalananda's solution (perhaps easier to remember?) but catering for all files(?):

```
array=("$(ls |sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)\..*/\1 &/'| sort -n | sed 's/^[^ ]* //')")
for x in "${array[@]}";do echo "$x";done
```

In essence add a sort key, sort, remove sort key.

EDIT: moved comment to appropriate solution

Comment: I'd rather stay away from non-standard flags. On Mac OSX, `ls -v` is "Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters; this is the default when output is not to a terminal.". On OpenBSD, it does not exist.

Comment: I didn't say you did. I was just commenting on your mentioning of `ls -v`.

Answer (score 0):

use sort -rh and the while loop

```
du -sh * | sort -rh | grep -P "avi$" |awk '{print $2}' | while read f; do fp=`pwd`/$f; echo $fp; done;
```