# Why does my sequence result in "syntax error near unexpected token"?

Tags: bash

I have written this code to ping multiple IP addresses but it does not work. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 'seq 1 20' do  
    ping -c 1 "10.88.209.$i";
done
```

ps: the error it is showing is =>
./ping.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `ping'
./ping.sh: line 3:`    ping -c 1 "10.88.209.$i";'

Comment: backticks around the command and a semicolon before the do : `for i in \`seq 1 20\`; do ..`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163619/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash

Comment: ./ping.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `ping'
./ping.sh: line 4: ` ping -c 1 "10.88.209.$i";'                        
this is the error it is showing

Comment: Add a `;` before `do`. Take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks, It's working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is broken. Single quotes and back-ticks are not interchangeable, and for-loops require a semicolon or newline before the `do` keyword. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in `seq 1 20`; do
    ping -c 1 "10.88.209.${i}"
done
```

Rather than spawning *seq*, you can also use the more efficient (and more idiomatic) Bash [brace-expansion sequence](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..20}; do
    ping -c 1 "10.88.209.${i}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
```

or

```
for i in {1..20}; do
```

or

```
for ((i=0;i<=20;i++)); do
```

obsolete:

```
for i in `seq 1 20`; do
```

Comment: Why the last one is obsolete?

Comment: Please see slm's detailed posting at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/74329) to this topic.