# BASH: loop files numbered by #{number} in sorted order

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, terminal

This was similar to [BASH: how to loop all files in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992689/bash-how-to-loop-all-files-in-sorted-order)
 but different enough I felt-

I have a series of files prepended with pound sign and number that in bash by default get ordered like this:

```
#1 Clear.png
#10 Brilliant Blue.png
#11 Caribbean Blue.png
#12 Aquamarine.png
#13 Teal.png
#14 Turquoise.png
#15 Green.png
#16 Light Green.png
#17 Purple.png
#18 Lt Purple.png
#19 Yellow.png
#2 Standard Pink.png
#20 Brown.png
#3 Light Pink.png
#4 Fuschia.png
#5 Wine.png
#6 Red.png
#7 Orange.png
#8 Blue.png
#9 Light Blue.png
```

Id like to sort these in a for loop by their numeric value in front of the pound sign in this order i.e. something like

```
for i in `ls * | sort [method to sort]`; do
*stuff*
done
```

The issue is that none of the sorting solutions I have found seem readily usable for sorting this case with a pound sign and/or spaces.

Order files should be sorted:

```
#1 Clear.png
#2 Standard Pink.png
#3 Light Pink.png
#4 Fuschia.png
#5 Wine.png
#6 Red.png
#7 Orange.png
#8 Blue.png
#9 Light Blue.png
#10 Brilliant Blue.png
#11 Caribbean Blue.png
#12 Aquamarine.png
#13 Teal.png
#14 Turquoise.png
#15 Green.png
#16 Light Green.png
#17 Purple.png
#18 Lt Purple.png
#19 Yellow.png
#20 Brown.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort -k 1.2 -n` should do the trick

`-k F.C` defines that input should be sorted according to field `F`, starting at character `C`. Both starting at 1

Edit: Just now I realize that my answer is pretty much the same answer to the question you linked. So definitely a duplicate

Comment: I think its different enough from the one I linked but maybe not from the one marked as duplicate which I hadn't seen. Thank you I think this is the answer anyways

Comment: You can add the n (numeric) in the keydef : sort -k1.2n